# Build fails with missing i386 architecture

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a physical folder called haxe and the .h and .m files inside. I import this folder to Xcode as it is, i do not make a group out of it.
In my code i import it like this and the project builds fine:

```
#import "haxe/Log.h"
```

However, if i want to use the static method it contains

```
[Log clear];
```

I get 2 build errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Log", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It's an ios6 app, i don't know what's the i386 doing there. In my Build Phases/Compile Sources the Log.m does not appear indeed, but appears the entire folder in Copy Bundle Resources

Thanks!

Comment: "i don't know what's the i386 doing there" <- Xcode assumes you want to build for the simulator. Dumb enough, right?

Comment: Haha, you're right. However, the error remains.

Comment: Remove the folder reference from the project and try adding again by selecting "create groups for any added folders". After that you can directly use it as #import "Log.h".

Comment: This way works, but in this case i'd like to do it with folder references.